# How create a service using soap and symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, soap

I want to create a web service using soap and Symfony2, but it gives me the following error:
Could not connect to host

This is my code:

```
    <?php
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Services;

class HelloService
{
    private $message;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->message = "Hola";
    }

    public function hello($name)
    {
        return $this->message+$name;
    }
}
?>

    #app/config/config.yml
services:
    hello_service:
        class: Acme\DemoBundle\Services\HelloService


 #app/config/routing.yml
servicio:
  pattern: /soap
  defaults: {_controller:AcmeDemoBundle:Demo:service}

cliente:
  pattern: /cliente
  defaults: {_controller:AcmeDemoBundle:Demo:cliente}


public function serviceAction() {
        $server = new \SoapServer('http://example.com/src/Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/views/Demo/hello.wsdl');
        $server->setObject($this->get('hello_service'));

        $response = new Response();
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1');

        ob_start();
        $server->handle();
        $response->setContent(ob_get_clean());
    }

 public function clienteAction(){
 $client = new \Soapclient('http://example.com/web/app_dev.php/soap?wsdl');
 $result = $client->call('hello', array('name' => 'Scott'));
    }
```

The url in the browser is: http://example.com/web/app_dev.php/cliente
What could be wrong?

Comment: does http://example.com/web/app_dev.php/soap?wsdl return valid XML wsdl?

Comment: I solved the problem by wiping the cache ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled',0);
 ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_ttl',0);

Comment: could you please add your findings as an answer then and accept it ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by wiping the cache ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled',0); ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_ttl',0);